# Reset stdin after reading from pipe

Tags: rust, terminal

I'm trying to read input (markdown) from stdin and then output that in a terminal-friendly way and with colored output. For that I determine the theme (light/dark) of the terminal using the [termbg](https://github.com/dalance/termbg) crate.

To read what's been piped to my program, I use this:

```
fn read_from_stdin() -> String {
  let stdin = io::stdin();
  let stdin_lock = stdin.lock();
  let buffer = stdin_lock.lines().filter_map(|l| l.ok()).fold("".to_string(), |acc, s| { format!("{acc}\n{s}")});
  return buffer;
}
```

After I've read from stdin, I try to find out if the terminal is using a light or dark theme using the `termbg` crate:

```
let timeout = std::time::Duration::from_millis(100);
let theme = termbg::theme(timeout);
match theme {
  Ok(t) => {
    println!("Detected theme: {:?}", t);
  },
  _ => {
    println!("No theme detected!"); // happens with tmux
  }
}
```

The problem is, termbg is trying to determine the theme by using OSC queries that apparently require the use of stdin/stdout.
Determining the right theme only works if I replace the reading from stdin with a hardcoded string **and** if I won't pass anything in via pipe.
So, apparently, termbg needs a clean and empty stdin to work properly but I can't find a way to make sure it gets that.

**How can I make sure that stdin is empty and in a state that termbg can work with before attempting to determine the right terminal theme?**

Complete testable code:

```
use std::{io::{self, BufRead}}

fn main() => io::Result<()> {
  let buffer = read_from_stdin();
  
  let timeout = std::time::Duration::from_millis(100);
  let theme = termbg::theme(timeout);
  match theme { // Mostly outputs wrong theme or none at all
    Ok(t) => {
      println!("Detected theme: {:?}", t);
    },
    _ => {
      println!("No theme detected!"); // happens with tmux
    }
  }
  
  // Parsing and formatting the markdown read from stdin would follow here but isn't relevant
  
  return Ok(());
}

fn read_from_stdin() -> String {
  let stdin = io::stdin();
  let stdin_lock = stdin.lock();
  let buffer = stdin_lock.lines().filter_map(|l| l.ok()).fold("".to_string(), |acc, s| { format!("{acc}\n{s}")});
  return buffer;
}
```

Comment: doesn't `read_from_stdin()` read until `EOF` is reached (by hitting `Ctrl-d`)? In this case, the file descriptor will not be usable anymore (except for closing), then `termbg` will not be able to use it in order to communicate with the terminal.

Comment: @prog-fh I'm passing markdown to the program like so: `cat markdownfile.md | myrustprogram`.

Comment: Then the standard input is not the terminal but the pipe. Doesn't `termbg` use the standard input?

Comment: @prog-fh yes, it is [using stdin here in fn from_xterm](https://github.com/dalance/termbg/blob/e9ca93d2a0c44fef53d667031fa72ed7d5bd2c06/src/lib.rs#L181).
btw: if I start my program without piped content and enter some markdown manually finishing it with `ctrl-d`, the theme detection actually seems to work. It just doesn't when content is piped to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot have the standard input already redirected at startup (by the shell here) and at the same time try to use the standard input to interact with the terminal.

Since the usage of `stdin` seems to be hardcoded in `termbg`, we have to let the standard input unchanged, and redirect to another file descriptor.

Here is an example reading from another file descriptor open by the shell.

Of course, it would be even easier to provide the file name to the program itself, but I assume the external redirection was needed for the real use case.

```rust
use std::{
    io::{IsTerminal, Read},
    os::fd::FromRawFd,
};

fn main() {
    println!(
        "is stdin still a terminal? ~~> {}",
        std::io::stdin().is_terminal()
    );
    let fd = 3;
    let mut input = unsafe { std::fs::File::from_raw_fd(fd) };
    let mut content = String::new();
    if let Ok(n) = input.read_to_string(&mut content) {
        println!("from fd {}, {} bytes: {:?}", fd, n, content);
    }
}
/*
$ (exec 3< file.txt ; cargo run)
is stdin still a terminal? ~~> true
from fd 3, 10 bytes: "Hi there!\n"
*/
```

Another solution, a bit more hacky but more convenient for the *pipe* situation you rely on, would be to duplicate the standard input to another file descriptor, **before** using the pipe.
This way, the standard input is redirected as usual to the pipe, so that we can read the content, but this new file descriptor still references the original terminal.
Once we are done with reading the standard input (from the pipe), we reassign the terminal to its initial file descriptor (with the classical `dup2()`/`close()` sequence, thanks to the [`libc` crate](https://crates.io/crates/libc)), then `std::io::stdin()` is a terminal again. Maybe `termbg` will work starting from this point.

```rust
use std::io::{IsTerminal, Read};

fn main() {
    println!(
        "is stdin initialy a terminal? ~~> {}",
        std::io::stdin().is_terminal()
    );
    let mut content = String::new();
    match std::io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut content) {
        Ok(n) => println!("from stdin, {} bytes: {:?}", n, content),
        Err(e) => println!("cannot read stdin: {:?}", e),
    }
    //~~~~ redirect fd 3 as stdin ~~~~
    let fd = 3;
    if unsafe { libc::dup2(fd, 0) } == -1 {
        println!("cannot redirect fd {} to stdin", fd);
        return;
    }
    if unsafe { libc::close(fd) } == -1 {
        println!("cannot close fd {}", fd);
        return;
    }
    //~~~~ stdin should be the terminal now ~~~~
    println!(
        "is stdin now a terminal? ~~> {}",
        std::io::stdin().is_terminal()
    );
}
/*
$ (exec 3<&0 ; echo "Hi there!" | cargo run )
is stdin initialy a terminal? ~~> false
from stdin, 10 bytes: "Hi there!\n"
is stdin now a terminal? ~~> true
*/
```

And to use this from your Perl script (instead of the shell) you can try

```perl
#~~~~ duplicate stdin as fd 3 ~~~~
use POSIX ();
POSIX::dup2(0, 3);
#~~~~ open a pipe to the stdin of the specified command ~~~~
open(my $my_pipe, '|-', 'cargo', 'run');
#~~~~ write anything into this pipe ~~~~
print $my_pipe "Hi there!\n";
```

Comment: So, the issue is, that me opening stdin like I do somehow changes stdin from being a terminal to being something else? Could I also use an "alternative" terminal in termbg? I'm not afraid of patching it and even submitting a PR. Since [there already is a PR](https://github.com/dalance/termbg/pull/19) for checking if it's still a terminal in termbg, it might actually solve someone elses problem too. (Also: yes, content from pipe is needed because the content is generated by a perl program.)

Comment: @wullxz I don't know the details of `termbg` but at first sight, `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` seem hardcoded everywhere. If you are ready to patch it, I suggest creating a structure with three optional files and make everything an implementation for this struct. When such an optional file is `None`, we use the standard one. Well, it's a total rewrite...
Or maybe hide this struct in a static variable (with proper locking), because standard IO are already static, and refer to this struct everywhere in the code without changing the function prototypes...

Comment: @wullxz I tried something you may find more convenient because you can still use the usual `|` pipe.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Don't I need to do the `libc` stuff before calling `stdin().read_to_string(&mut content)`?

Comment: @wullxz no because you need to read from the pipe. Once it's done, stdin can be the terminal again.

Comment: The perl program actually calls this program, which means that it would still have to create the fd 3 so my rust program could swap it around. I've even tried to handle the creation of a temporary file/fd and calling my program recursively to re-pass the content on fd 3 but that didn't work and was also very hacky. You were right with your first sentence in your answer. I thank you for your effort to make this work.

Comment: @wullxz I added some few lines of Perl that do this.